# pandas dataframe- replace row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with four columns (see input dataframe below). I need to check if Meta column has pattern relation (example M_relation) then add number from relation column to the meta column value. How this can be done in pandas?

Input dataframe:

```
--------------------------------------

    Entry1 | Relation | Entry2 | Meta |

--------------------------------------

E11 | R_31 | E21 | M_xxx |

E12 | R_21 | E51 | M_relation |

E33 | R_21 | E51 | M_yyy |

E44 | R_41 | E46 | M_relation |
```

---

Output:

```
--------------------------------------
Entry1 | Relation | Entry2 | Meta |
--------------------------------------

E11 | R_31 | E21 | M_xxx |

E12 | R_21 | E51 | M_relation_21 |

E33 | R_21 | E51 | M_yyy |

E44 | R_41 | E46 | M_relation_41 |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
pattern = df.Meta.str.split('_').str.get(1) == 'relation'
df.loc[pattern, 'Meta'] = df.loc[pattern, 'Meta'] + '_' + df.loc[pattern, 'Relation'].str.split('_').str.get(1)
```

to get:

```
  Entry1 Relation Entry2           Meta
0    E11     R_31    E21          M_xxx
1    E12     R_21    E51  M_relation_21
2    E33     R_21    E51          M_yyy
3    E44     R_51    E51  M_relation_51
```